# Number of Linearly independent n-vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Fron page 15, Springer Text, Matrix Algebra.

It says

"the maximum number of *n-vectors* that can form a linearly independent set is *n*

How can it be proved? Thanks :-)

Comment: Perhaps that text has an explanation of this?  Most linear algebra textbooks do.

Comment: No, the text just states it without proof

Comment: Directing me to particular textbooks is also fine. Thanks

Comment: I thought about it this way. Let the number of n-vectors is 'n'. The set formed should have a maximum number of vectors. In this case, it is 'n'. The set formed is linearly independent i.ewhich means that it just includes all the vectors and it is equal to 'n'. Can some one please verify?